# Git for windows - switch credential to my account

Tags: git, github

I have installed 'git for window' from https://git-scm.com/download/win.
When I tried to git clone my github repository using http connect, I wasn't asked for authentication and clone the file successfully. However, when I committed and pushed the file and checked it from github web page. It turned that I was committing using my friends' account (But I am actually using my credential to login in github page which popped up during my push command). Why it always showed that the changes are made by my friends' account?
Edit: I have checked the following webpage and erase generic credential stored in my local space:
[Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

Comment: Because you probably need to run `git config -- local user.name ...`, same for `user.email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It turned that I was committing using my friends' account

Your commits have nothing to do with the authentication you provide when pushing.
They have to do with `git config user.name` and `git config user.email`: enter the same username/email than the one used in your GitHub account, and your next commits will show up as you (meaning as your GitHub account)
That won't influence your past commits though: see "[GitHub help page 'Changing author info'](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/)" for that.

Again: `user.name` and `user.email` are *local* configs used when creating commits, and can be completely different from the GitHub account credentials used for pushing.

Comment: Thank you so much, that really helps